# Why is constexpr part of the type?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, constexpr

why is constexpr part of the line ? I thought it was just like inline.
What's the real type of `f` in `g` ?

This works:

```
void f()
{
  auto f = []() { return 42; };
  auto p = f;

  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(f), decltype(p)>);
}
```

but this doesn't:

```
void g()
{
  constexpr auto f = []() { return 42; };
  auto p = f;

  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(f), decltype(p)>);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/Di4SJ5

Comment: By "works", do you mean the assertion passes or fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) makes the object `const`, so the type of `f` is `const` `the_lambda_type`, while `p` is non-`const` (which is a new object copied from `f`).

> A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration implies `const`.

The following `static_assert` would be fine.

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::remove_const_t<decltype(f)>, decltype(p)>);
```

BTW:

> What's the real type of `f` in `g` ?

You can use an undefined class template to get the real type from the compiling error message, such as

```
template <typename>
struct TD;
```

then

```
constexpr auto f = []() { return 42; };
auto p = f;

TD<decltype(f)> td1;
TD<decltype(p)> td2;
```

e.g. the error message of [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/087N3L5LLkEbMu0x) looks like:

> ```
> prog.cc:14:21: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'TD<const (lambda at prog.cc:9:24)>'
>     TD<decltype(f)> td1;
>                     ^
> prog.cc:15:21: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'TD<(lambda at prog.cc:9:24)>'
>     TD<decltype(p)> td2;
> ```

and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Is `f()` a constant expression? (in either case), in C++17?

Comment: @M.M I‘m not sure. I tried it [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qcl0C80Tllyhx4qJ), the answer seems to be "yes", whether it's `constexpr` or not.

Comment: it makes sense that the result of a constant expression should be constexpr, otherwise you couldn't say X<foo()>.
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57ab736ff738f72b